# Парсинг неправильного JSON | Python

Tags: python, json, парсер, csv, txt

Имеется вот такая неправильная выгруженная коллекция из MongoDB:

```
"title": "Инструкция конец"
"createdBy": "test@test.ru"
"dateCreated": ISODate("2022-08-03T12:14:09.881+0000")
"fileName": "Инструкция конец.docx"
"title": "Blueprint"
"createdBy": "test@test.ru"
"dateCreated": ISODate("2022-08-03T11:59:03.109+0000")
"fileName": "Blueprint.pdf"
"title": "Contract"
"createdBy": "test@test.ru"
"dateCreated": ISODate("2022-08-03T11:59:03.552+0000")
"fileName": "Contract.docx"
"title": "Marketing report"
"createdBy": "test@test.ru"
"dateCreated": ISODate("2022-08-03T11:59:03.755+0000")
"fileName": "Marketing report.pptx"
"title": "Blueprint"
```

Легко открывается вот так:

```
with open('C:\base.json', "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
```

Нативным JSON, разумеется, не является. По сути это простой TXT. Нужно получить полную выборку, желательно в виде табличного файла, например, CSV.
Требуются все(4) "ключи" и из значения:

```
"dateCreated": | "fileName" | "title": | "createdBy":
```

Будет круто, если можно будет присвоить свои ключи и подставить к ним значения, чтобы получилось подобное:

[image: пример]

Буду благодарен, если подскажите, как лучше реализовать. Получится ли такое вообще в нормальный словарь преобразовать с небольшими усилиями?

Comment: А с чем у вас возникла сложность? или вам готовое дать?

Comment: Я совсем молодой в изучении Питона. Изначально выгрузка ещё более неупорядоченная была. Самостоятельно смог привести к такому виду, а что дальше делать, понимаю не очень, поэтому прошу помощи. Хотя бы подсказать, как лучше реализовать.

Comment: каждую строку split(": "'') потом strip('"') или replace('"', '') получите пары ключ-значение, дальше просто цикл по четыре, или до следующего title

Comment: читаете строку, разбиваете (split) по знаку ```:```, первая часть - ключ, вторая значение. Далее если точно уверены что записей по 4 штуки - то просто скидываете по 4 в пачку, если нет - сложнее но тоже возможно.

Comment: Вроде разбил как надо, но не пойму, как правильно перебрать?

Answer (score 1):

Не надо называть `json` то что json не является. Но опустим пока эту несуразицу.
То что не парсит json, обычно довольно неплохо парсит [yaml](/questions/tagged/yaml):

```python
import yaml
d = {}
with open('base.json', "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f:
        for k,v in yaml.safe_load(line).items():
            d.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
```

###### Переменная `d`:

```
{'title': ['Инструкция конец',
  'Blueprint',
  'Contract',
  'Marketing report',
  'Blueprint'],
 'createdBy': ['test@test.ru', 'test@test.ru', 'test@test.ru', 'test@test.ru'],
 'dateCreated': ['ISODate("2022-08-03T12:14:09.881+0000")',
  'ISODate("2022-08-03T11:59:03.109+0000")',
  'ISODate("2022-08-03T11:59:03.552+0000")',
  'ISODate("2022-08-03T11:59:03.755+0000")'],
 'fileName': ['Инструкция конец.docx',
  'Blueprint.pdf',
  'Contract.docx',
  'Marketing report.pptx']}
```

## В таблицу

Получили довольно внятный словарь, который теперь можно запихнуть в [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas). Ну почти. В приведённом примере последнему **title** (Blueprint) нет соответствующих строк в других колонках, DataFrame так не собрать. Надеюсь у тебя данные более полные.
Но пока на данном этапе уберём данную оплошность:

```python
max_rows = max(len(l) for l in d.values())
for v in d.values():
    while len(v) < max_rows:
        v.append(None)
```

Отлично, теперь можно собрать DataFrame.

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

# Приводим колонку с датой к datetime
df['dateCreated'] = pd.to_datetime(df.dateCreated.str.replace(r'.*\("|"\)',''))

# Переименовываем колонки
df = df.rename(columns={'title': 'Заголовок',
                        'createdBy': 'Загрузил',
                        'dateCreated': 'Дата загрузки',
                        'fileName': 'Название файла'})

# Сортируем колонки
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[-2:] + cols[:2]
df = df[cols]

# Длинную дату вида "2022-08-03 12:14:09.881000+00:00" приводим к короткому варианту
df['Дата загрузки'] = df['Дата загрузки'].dt.date

print(df)
```

###### Вывод:

```
  Дата загрузки         Название файла         Заголовок      Загрузил
0    2022-08-03  Инструкция конец.docx  Инструкция конец  test@test.ru
1    2022-08-03          Blueprint.pdf         Blueprint  test@test.ru
2    2022-08-03          Contract.docx          Contract  test@test.ru
3    2022-08-03  Marketing report.pptx  Marketing report  test@test.ru
4           NaT                   None         Blueprint          None
```

Дальше DataFrame можно сохранить в **csv** одной строчкой:

```python
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Вместо csv можно сохранить в **excel**:

```python
df.to_excel("out.xlsx")
```

Comment: Спасибо! Пригодится!

Comment: @Nick комментарии на StackOverflow не для спасибо, почитайте [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)